# Need help navigating the Google developer app to set up XOAUTH2 for phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

I have been banging my head against a wall for the last two weeks. I'm trying to set up a contact me web page for my business. Having read all the warnings about mailto, I opted to use phpmailer for this. Similarly, I decided to use XOAUTH2 for sending the mail through gmail. I found several sites, including instructions at the [phpmailer github page](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2), that should have walked me through doing this.

Here's where I run into problems. After logging into the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), creating my project, and enabling the gmail api, all of the sites that I found talk about creating my new client ID. Every single one of them tell me that I will get a simple pop-up where I click that I want to create a web application, fill in a few items, and voila, out will pop my ID. When I did this, however, I was required to complete the consent screen before I could do anything else, and these screens did not match anything that was shown on the web sites I used as a guide. I muddled through as best I could and did finally get a client ID (I think/hope).

Does anyone know of a site or sites that walk a person through this in a way that matches what the development site actually displays? Did Google recently change things and the help sites haven't caught up? Having to guess at some of this is definitely not the way to do things. I'll be testing the results in a couple of days, but won't be surprised if things don't work right. At that point, I'll probably need more help to figure out what went wrong.

Thank you for listening to my rant.

Comment: As the one who wrote that guide, I know what you mean. It's difficult because Google is always making small changes to things, and so it's hard to keep docs up to date. One thing to remember though – this is open source. If you find a discrepancy (even if it's just a small difference, and not necessarily a complete solution), note the change yourself and submit a PR, rather than lamenting that someone else hasn't fixed it.

Comment: @Synchro - I agree with you about updating the document myself. I just had to rant for a bit and ask if anyone had a more up to date document. I would have expected Google to at least provide better guidance. What I did didn't work, so I'll probably have to start over again. I'll try to document the process so that an update can be made. I may also post questions as I go along to get help with particular spots.